# Testing multiple configurations of parameterizable modules in a Verilog testbench

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, test-bench, icarus

Say I have a Verilog module that's parameterizable like the below example:

```
// Crunches numbers using lots of parallel cores
module number_cruncher
    #(parameter NUMBER_OF_PARALLEL_CORES = 4)
    (input clock, ..., input [31:0] data, ... etc);
    // Math happens here
endmodule
```

Using Verilog 1364-2005, I want to write a testbench that runs tests on this module with many different values `NUMBER_OF_PARALLEL_CORES`.

One option that I know will work is to use a `generate` block to create a bunch of different `number_cruncher`s with different values for `NUMBER_OF_PARALLEL_CORES`. This isn't very flexible, though - the values need to be chosen at compile time.

Of course, I could also explicitly instantiate a lot of different modules, but that is time consuming and won't work for the sort of "fuzz" testing I want to do.

My questions:

- Is there a way to do this by using a plusarg passed in from the command line using `$value$plusargs`? (I strongly suspect the answer is 'no' for Verilog 1364-2005).
- Is there another way to "fuzz" module parameterizations in a testbench, or is using a generate block the only way?

Comment: If you do not mind recompiling for every separate test, you can generated the constant using a script before compilation. Also, some compilers allow you to define parameters in a compilation switch.

Comment: Does the dut allow you to enable fewer cores than available? If so what is the difference between a 4 core all enabled and a 8 core half enabled?

Comment: @Greg this is just a silly hypothetical example. This is a great suggestion I hadn't thought of, but it's not applicable to every scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `$value$plusargs` is evaluated at runtime, it can not be used to set `parameter` values, which must be done at compile-time.

However, if you use `generate` to instantiate multiple instances of the design with different `parameter` settings, you might be able to use `$value$plusargs` to selectively activate or enable one instance at a time.  For example, in the testbench, you could use the runtime argument to only drive the inputs of a specific instance.